# Pulling Firebas .json file into r

Tags: json, r, curl, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I currently have a program that scrapes the text and author and time stamp from the news websites I visit and pushes it to a firebase database in .json format. I'm now pulling that data into r to perform all the fun sentiment & nlp analysis. When i first started I had the data public and, using curl, I could easily pull the .json data into r. Code:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
# grab the data
raw_data <- getURL("https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/.json)
# covert from JSON into a list in R
dataJSON <- fromJSON(raw_data)
```

I have since switched the firebase database from public to private and now when i run the above code I receive a "Permission Denied" error. The question I have is how can I access my json data now that I have switched from public to private?

I created a Service admin account in firebase and generated a private key after reading that would give me an auth token that I could use in something like this format:

```
curl 'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack/name.json?access_token=<TOKEN>'
```

But in the private key there is no "token".

If anyone has any insight or recommendations it'd be hugely appreciated!

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth ; use `httr`